# Flutter - How to use class-wide state with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a button that uses a counter provider with Riverpod, I would like to add a local state `isLoading` to the button.

While I can do it all inside the `build` method, I'm wondering if there is a way to lift the state to the instance level so that other methods inside the `Btn` class can also access this state, for instance, making `onPressed` function into another method.

The code with everything inside `build`:

```dart
class Btn extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const Btn({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final isLoading = useState(false);
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);
    final counterNotifier = ref.read(counterProvider.notifier);
    useEffect(() {
      if (isLoading.value) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          isLoading.value = false;
          counterNotifier.reset();
        });
      }
      return null;
    }, [isLoading.value]);

    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      onPressed: () => isLoading.value = true : null,
      icon: isLoading.value ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(),
      label:Text(isLoading.value ? "Loading" : "$counter"),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to turn it into:

```dart
class Btn extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const Btn({super.key});

  // declare isLoading

  void onPressed() {
    isLoading.value = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);
    final counterNotifier = ref.read(counterProvider.notifier);
    useEffect(() {
      if (isLoading.value) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          isLoading.value = false;
          counterNotifier.reset();
        });
      }
      return null;
    }, [isLoading.value]);

    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      icon: isLoading.value ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(),
      label: Text(isLoading.value ? "Loading" : "$counter"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Btn is a standard class.  You can add your own properties to the notifier, or even add it to the static level (class level) to be shared amongst family members, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your class into a `ConsumerStatefullWidget` and discard the hooks, then all your parameters can become class fields.

Furthermore, try not to pull logic into the widget. There is business logic, then place it in a notifier class (and even use an `AsyncNotifier` that contains "sealed" state with data, load and error). If it's ui logic, it's not a bad option to place it in the presenter classes.

All of this will increase code reusability and allow each layer of your application to clearly fulfill its responsibilities.

Comment: Is it an overkill to put one variable into a provider? Or is this the boilerplate with Riverpod? In this case, the loading state of the button.

Comment: @James, One `Provider` variable is one state. Is the state complicated? - then it is a `Notifier` class with methods to manage this state. If the state is asynchronous, you can use `FutureProvider` for simple cases and `AsyncNotifier` for complex cases. It's not even about the riverpod itself, it's about the design style. Each class (read as a provider) should have its own area of responsibility and there's a question of how comprehensive that state is.